# Appending pid to filename

Tags: c, linux

While coding for server-client program using c in linux, I need to append pid of the client process to the fifo filename(fifo file which will be used to send the data back to the client). (The concept of the sever-client program is for server to read the data from the client, compute the data, and send the data back to client for it to display it.) I wish to do this for multiple clients and single server. This way I will be able to have different fifo files for every execution of client file. And to achieve this I need the server to append the pid of client process to the fifo file name.(for eg. if the fifo file name is 'myfifo' and the pid of client is '2891' the resultant fifo filename should be 'myfifo2891')Can anyone help me achieve this? How do I append the pid to the fifo file name? I am thinking of using a structure for it.

Answer (score 3):

You can use snprintf() to achieve this:
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/snprintf/

> int snprintf ( char * s, size_t n, const char * format, ... );

So in your case:

```
char filename_buffer[64];
int string_len= 0;
pid_t pid = getpid();

string_len = snprintf(filename_buffer, sizeof(filename_buffer),
                   "%s%d", filename, (int) pid);
if (string_len < 0 || string_len > sizeof(filename_buffer)) { /* Handle error here */ }
```

Comment: If `filename_buffer` is an array -which is a common situation-, e.g. declared as `char filename_buffer[64];`, then use `sizeof(filename_buffer)` as the 2nd argument (e.g. as `length_of_buffer`)

Comment: Yeah, you are correct. I will edit it into my answer as it is the more correct way to go about it.

Comment: Also, you probably should tell `pid_t pid = getpid();`  for clarity (and use `(int)pid`  in your `snprintf` call)

Comment: Alright, thanks for the input!

Also, sorry for the edit wars, new to stackoverflow :)

Comment: BTW, I find the name `errcode` not very well chosen. Don't you think that `slen` would be more appropriate (since it is usually a string length...)

Comment: I agree on that, but wouldn't 'retval' be more appropriate, since it can return a negative number when it encounters encoding errors?

Comment: Yes, but a too small buffer is more likely than an error (in this particular case for `"%s%d"` , I believe that `snprintf` won't fail with error, but might need a larger buffer)

Answer (score -4):

The variable $$ contains the PID of the current process in Linux.

Comment: Wrong. The *shell* variable `$$`  containts the PID of the shell and has no significance in C (so often `getenv("$$")`  is `NULL`)